# Chrome doesn't connect to Java HTTP Server

Tags: java, html, http, browser, server

I have this simple HTTP Server:

```
public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        Test t = null;
        int port = 9000;
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
        System.out.println("server started at " + port);
        server.createContext("/", new Start());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    }

}
```

And this class which serves the html page:

```
public class Start implements HttpHandler{

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(
                Paths.get("Views/start.html"));
        String response =  new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        he.getRequestHeaders().set("Content-type:", "text/html");
        OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }

}
```

After putting it to run, I access a browser (Chrome in this case) to load this simple html page via localhost:9000:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Start</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Start</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

However, what I see is this error message:

This page isn’t working
localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.
ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

If someone knows what I'm doing wrong, please let me know. By the way, the problem is the same with Firefox. The only browser so far which can load properly is the Eclipse internal browser.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 3 problems with your code.

1. You tried to set request's header in line `he.getRequestHeaders().set("Content-type:", "text/html");`. Instead of it you should set response's header
2. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#sendResponseHeaders-int-long-

> If the response length parameter is greater than zero, this specifies
>   an exact number of bytes to send and the application must send that
>   exact amount of data

But your code set not number of bytes but length of `String` - it's not the same.

3. Don't add ":" to header's name.

Working example:

```
public class Start implements HttpHandler{

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(
                Paths.get("Views/start.html"));
        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, encoded.length);
        he.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "text/html");
        OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
        os.write(encoded);
        os.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I'd just add your answer to deal with the response string, otherwise, it will keep a compilation error.

Comment: Nice! Thank you!